Android - DND permission from Unit tests
I'm writing unit tests to test the notification service layer. So while testing out the create channel feature, I would like to test all of the properties of the NotificationChannel object. Hence, I'm trying to test the 'setBypassDnd' as well.
So from the instrumentation tests, I have written a test to test this scenario but I realised that a channel can have this Override DND be true only if the app has already been granted the same permission.
I have already granted the post_notifications permission as below to test the notification presentation.
    @get:Rule
val permissionRule: GrantPermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(
    android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
)

So my question is, is there a way to grant the OverrideDND permission from within the tests?
